# Is commutation transitive for permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $f,g,h$ be bijections from some set $X$ to itself, i.e. they are permutations of $X$. We say that $f$ and $g$ *commute* if $f\circ g=g\circ f$.

Is it the case, in general, that if $f$ commutes with $h$, and $g$ commutes with $h$, then $f$ commutes with $g$?

If not, is it always the case if $X$ is finite?

If not, could somebody give a counter example? (It seems like it shouldn't be true, but I can't think of one.)

Comment: @sea turtles: of course the OP intends $fg = gf$.

Comment: @Nathaniel: by Cayley's theorem, this is true for all $X$ iff it's true for all groups, and true for all finite $X$ iff it's true for all finite groups. What examples have you tried?

Comment: @Qiaochu you're quite right about that typo. (The perils of typing LaTeX on an iphone. Now fixed.) I tried a bunch of examples for finite $X$ up to size 6 or so, but didn't find any counterexamples.

Comment: @Nathaniel: did you try taking $h$ to be the identity?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan apparently I didn't drink enough coffee before thinking about this this morning. Thanks! Feel free to post that as an answer if you'd like the points.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Cayley's theorem, you can realize any group as a permutation group. But there exist noncommutative transitive* groups: take for example a nonabelian group whose center is nontrivial (eg. quaternion group).

*that is a group that is not commutative transitive (nothing to do with [transitive groups](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroup.html)): a group $G$ is said commutative transitive if two elements of $G$ commuting with a third nontrivial element commute.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The question is whether the relation "$f$ commutes with $g$" is transitive.

Comment: If commutation were transitive, a group $G$ with a nontrivial center $Z$ would be abelian: if $g,h \in G$, then $g$ commutes with any $k \in Z$ and $k$ commutes with $h$, so $h$ and $g$ commute. So quaternion group seems to be a counterexample to the question.

Comment: The center doesn't even need to be nontrivial: you can just take one of the elements to be the identity. But transitive permutation groups have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I think I understand the problem: A group $G$ is said commutative transitive if two elements of $G$ commuting with a third nontrivial element of $G$ commute. So, by a noncommutative transitive group, I mean a group that is not commutative transitive, and not a nonabelian transitive group. Maybe it is not clear in my answer. By the way, I know that it is sufficient to take the identity, but I found more interesting to deal with commutative transtive groups to get more evolved counterexamples.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Was it really a problem of vocabulary? Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$